# What are 'dup0' files in the photos folder?

Tags: photos, files

Today when I wanted to copy some photos and videos from my Samsung Galaxy S to my PC, I noticed that inside the photos folder (DCIM\Camera) there are a lot of files with the extension `dup0`. They have the same filename as the photos/movies (e.g. img1.jpg and img1.dup0), but not for every photo a `dup0` file exists.

What are these files for? Can they be deleted to free some space?

**Update / additional information**: the `dup0` files are quite small for photos (e.g. photos are about 1.5 MB, dup0 files about 50 kB), but for movies, they can be quite large (e.g. 16 MB for an 18 MB movie).

Answer (score 2):

Rename the file with the appropriate extension and find out(ie rename img1.dup0 to img1-1.jpg and open it). In the case of the image files I think they are the corresponding thumbnails since the size is small

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a Linux/Unix PC (including OSX), you can use the `file` utility to identify the file type. For Windows, you can install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to get a Unix environment that will have this utility.